# Does Lighting Shriekers ability activate if it dies or was exiled?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So if anyone noticed I've been asking a few random unrelated questions since last night
Im new to magic and I bought a box of bulk common cards to get started (Theres been a few I added to my main deck, but mostly Im using it to learn how the game works.)

So I have a [Lightning Shrieker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Shrieker)

So it says "At the begining of the end step, Lightning Shrieker's owner shuffles it into their library."

Does this take effect if it died or was exiled? And if so what can keep it from being returned to the library?

I actually did find an answer to this question (But it was on tumblr so I don't really trust they know, because of what I say next) and they said if it dies it does mot return to the library, and it can only be returned from the battlefield

The main reason I don't trust this is because while reading my bulk of cards I've seen a good number of cards that say "Return (Creature name) to (Place) from battlefield"

And this one does not say "from battlefield"

Edit: Sorry I should have been more clear, I know it doesn't activate by being exiled or destroyed, my question was when I get to the end step does the trigger still activate from exile or the graveyard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no conditional on that effect, except "At the beginning of the end step".

Roughly speaking, any effect is going to apply only when the card is in play, "on the battlefield", unless the effect specifies otherwise.

So the effect takes place when it says it does, roughly at the end of the current turn.  Not when it dies or is exiled.  Since the card has Haste, in effect, you get a 5/5 attacker with flying & trample for one turn only that then gets shuffled back into your deck.  Unless you have some other way to tinker with the mechanics, that effect will always take place at the end of any turn.

To clarify further, your tumblr information is correct; if it dies, and is in the graveyard at end of turn, the effect will not apply, and it will stay in the graveyard.

Something that can exile the card and then bring it back the next turn would, temporarily, circumvent the effect, if you want to keep it in play. (I thought there was a Blink card that would do this, but cannot find it now).

Comment: Anything like Flickerwisp can delay the trigger for one turn by blinking the creature. You can also use Sundial of the Infinite :)